# Two orchard thieves

Tags: meaning

In Herman Melville's *Moby Dick* there is the passage

> The act of paying is perhaps the most uncomfortable infliction that the two orchard thieves entailed upon us.

Who are those *two orchard thieves* ?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Please follow the rules and do not answer questions in comments.

Comment: @David Answers should be corroborated by reliable references. This would probably be tricky in this case. Also, this is a literary rather than a language question.

Comment: @David I was making an uneducated guess. If I had known for sure, I would have made it an answer. The question is asking for literary interpretation, anyway, which is off-topic—another reason I didn’t look any further in order to verify if my guess was true and write an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a niche usage in literature rather than standard English usage.

Comment: I think I was partly wearing my [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) hat when (*after* upvoting @Janus's comment), I went in search of a "reliable reference" rather than closevoting for lack of prior research. The question arises: *How far should ELU be prepared to go in terms of covering Anglophone (historically, predominantly Christian) **culture**, as opposed to language?* On reflection, and after reading later comments above, I'm thinking *Not this far!*

Comment: @Dmitri Pisarenko: I'll leave my answer there because I'm not sure if you'll still be able to see it if I delete it (I think you need high rep to see deleted answers). If you're soldiering through *Moby Dick,* you might find my link saves you coming back here with similar questions. :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet — You will have read the following when you opened the comment box: “Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.” I suppose you could say this comment doesn't fit either. But I regard it as a courtesy to you to explain why I will flag your comment (and others of this type that I encounter) to the moderators.

Comment: @David Again, _I did not answer the question in a comment_. An unfounded guess is emphatically **not** an answer. Presenting speculative possibilities to get the ball rolling has not generally been considered outside the scope of what comments are for, and flagging such comments for moderator attention is highly unlikely to do any good. I actually agree with you that answers in comments detract from the site; but a comment is not automatically an answer just because it happens to give the correct answer to the question. SE answers adhere to higher standards than that.

Comment: @David: I can't speak for the mods, but I think you'll find you're flogging a dead horse there. As Janus says (and as I now agree), the question is Off Topic anyway. But even if it weren't, why should you care so much about people posting *information, suggestions* in comments?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet — I do not wish to argue with you. All I ask is that you and others read what comes up in the comment box and abide by it, regardless of “what is or is not generally considered…”

Comment: @David This is not an issue that should be discussed on the ELU main board. If you think users should not post an answer in a comment, you can write up a Meta question. However, it will very likely be closed as duplicate of http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/why-are-answers-being-posted-in-the-comments-on-the-question which is a master duplicate of http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/8104/whats-the-rationale-for-responding-to-a-question-with-a-comment-as-opposed-to-a.

Comment: @Rathony — I am not discussing the question. As common courtesy I am telling someone why I have flagged his contribution. I do not believe in hiding behind anonymity. As for Meta, thank you for your observations, but when I have a moment I will add my contribution to the existing discussion.

Comment: @David First of all, welcome to English Language and Usage. I have seen several cases where you made the same comment asking users not to post an answer as a comment. Nothing good will come out of this comment. For the record, I also believe an answer should not be posted as a comment. However, such a short answer is better left in a comment than in the answer box which requires a definitive answer with a proper link and reference. We have to meet in the middle ground sometimes. You will get accustomed to it as time goes by. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Melville's Allusions to Religion: A Comprehensive Index and Glossary:](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oPhOttJTaPIC&pg=PA252&dq=%22the%20two%20orchard%20thieves%22%20-%22perhaps%20the%20most%20uncomfortable%20infliction%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20two%20orchard%20thieves%22%20-%22perhaps%20the%20most%20uncomfortable%20infliction%22&f=false)

> **the two orchard thieves** - *Adam and Eve*

Answer (score 3):

It appears he is referring to ***Adam  and Eve:***

> - In Moby-Dick Ishmael often reminds us that Christians do not always abide by what they preach. With a passing reference to Adam and Eve, “the two orchard thieves,” in the first chapter of the book, he avows that ever since the Garden of Eden humankind has been attempting to “pay off” an ever-lurking debt to God that has evolved into an installment payment and continuous burden for humankind.

([chasingflukes.com](https://chasingflukes.com/reading_guide-overview/glossary-contents/1orchard-thieves/))